# Text File Art Manipulation Python

Tags: python

i'm currently working on a project for taking .png/.gif images and turning them it into ASCII and saving it to a text file. The way I achieved this was by getting the Gray Scale average of each pixel then have 2 for loops going through the pictures height and width then appending all of it into a 2 dimensional List(example below).

Assuming it was a 50x50 image:

[[Y1], [X1, X2, X3, X4, X5..., X50]]

[[Y2], [X1, X2, X3, X4, X5..., X50]]

[[Y3], [X1, X2, X3, X4, X5..., X50]]

...

[[Y50], [X1, X2, X3, X4, X5..., X50]]

I then use a small loop like this to write it to the notepad:

```
for z in range(0, len(yList)):
    for q in yList[z]:
        filename123.write(q)
    filename123.write('\n')
```

This gave me my 50x50 ASCII art saved to a notepad without being distorted, shifted, etc.. .

My question now is, I want to be able to open the file I created in Python and be able to manipulate the ASCII art I have saved in text by doing things such as flipping it on either axis or rotate it 90 degrees(I opened the file and read it, the ASCII image is printing in console after making 'variable = filename.read()' then printing that variable). How would I go about doing these kind of manipulations with the text file?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, it's quite simple to flip and rotate; read the `x, y` values of the image in different orders. I highly recommend combining transformations to create some sort of notation that contains the following information:

```
x/y first?
first or last first for x?
first or last for y?
```

Calculate this information by combining rotation/mirroring transformations, then use it to iterate the image.

Your pipeline would look something like this:

```
image -> mirroring notation -> rotation notation 
-> mirroring + rotation = transformation -> iterate through image
-> spit out ASCII
```

Comment: I'm not using the actual image file for this, just the ASCII symbols in the .txt file.

Comment: In that case, just apply the transformation on the text file :)